# Tiebreakers for best loser in a single elimination playoff

Tags: rules, football, tie-breaker

In an instance where three teams were beaten by 3:1, 4:2 and 5:3, which team qualifies as best losers?

Answer (score 0):

In football, in case of equal goal differences, usually the goals scored are more important than the goals conceded. So, in your case the best loser will be the one who lost 3:5.

For instance, [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup_qualification#Tiebreakers) you can take a look at tiebreakers used during the World Cup.